# Angularjs Directive templateUrl in MVC 5 without angularjs routing mechanism

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I have been trying to call angularjs custom directive templateUrl in Razor view MVC 5 but unable to get the file in.
In my project I am using angularjs without its $routeProvider or angularjs routing because my app depends on mvc routing directly.
can some one help me out with this please.

```html
These are my templates.... 
~/Areas/Sales/Views/Orders/Edit.cshtml ~/Areas/Sales/Views/Orders/Add.cshtml ~/Areas/Sales/Views/Orders/Update.cshtml ~/Areas/Sales/Views/Orders/Delete.cshtml 

This is my directive. 

app.directive("test", function(){ 
return{ 
restrict:'AE',
scope: { 
emp: '='
},
templateUrl: '~/Areas/Sales/Views/Orders/Edit.cshtml' 
}
});
```

Comment: **Claies**, I just simply want to use directive with templateUrl option in MVC 5 but don't know how to load templateUrl  files in here. Can you explain me.

Comment: **Claies**, Can you provide any working example?

Comment: **Claies**, Can you suggest me the correct way, because I am about to create alot of directives so before that I want to be clear whats the standard way of creating directives in mvc 5

Comment: **Claies**, copy that, but how do I call an .html file in templateUrl in MVC 5?

Comment: **Claies**, Do I really hard-code my domain name or FQDN?

Comment: **Claies**, Right now I am inside the area name "Common" inside controller "Home" using action as "Index", there under Home I created a file called Save.html and using this in my directive templateUrl:"/Common/Home/Save.html" and it says ...  [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /Common/Home/Save.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: **Claies**, Am I making any mistake here, can you please correct me? I was showing the path where I am working actually!!!

Comment: **Claies**, I am very new to directives hardly trying to learn because its very complex you know that, just need small push from someone here so I can get started with this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/index', {
                templateUrl: '/home/index',
                controller: 'QuizController' //new
            }).
            when('/quiz', {
                templateUrl: '/home/quiz',
                controller: 'QuizController' //new
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/index'
            });
    }]);
```

```html
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: **Arvind Audacious**, I dont want to use **$routeProvider** in my app. and I am not trying to route to a particular view, but want to include a directive inside my another view as directives work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem;
app.directive('parentDirective', function ($http, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var controllerurl = attrs.controllerurl;
        elem = element;

        if (controllerurl) {
          return function(scope,element){
            $http.get(controllerurl + '/GetWizardItems').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var x = angular.element('<child-directive></child-directive><child-directive></child-directive>');
                element.append(x);
                $compile(x)(scope);
            });
          }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this with my solution please.